# Is this possible to assign ng-model value from anchor rag(<a ../>)

Tags: angularjs

My question is
when I click the edit link in the table model-dialog want to open and its
value should be assigned in there field. Here dialog will opening but the 
value will not getting initialized.

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
<form method="POST" action="Projects" >
    <div class="modal fade" id="update" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
<label for="Project_Id"> Project Id</label>
<input readonly="readonly" ng-model=project_id class="form-control"
     id="project_id" value=""  />
     </div>
     </div>
     </form>
```

MY question is
when I click the edit link in the table model-dialog want to open and its
value should be assigned in there field. Here dialog will opening but the 
value will not getting initialized.

```
    <table>
     <thead><tr><td>  Edit </td></tr></thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="values in records ">
       <td>
<a data-toggle="modal"  ng-model=values.projectId 
             ng-href="#update"</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('Projects').success(function (data) {                
 $scope.records = data;  
 $scope.project_id=$scope.data.projectId;
     // $scope.project_id="some value" ...if i remove this comment it is working properly some value will be shown, but I need particular record  data.projectId should be displayed
     });
</script>
```

Comment: did you try to use `ng-init`?

Comment: try `$scope.project_id=data.projectId;` it looks like either you have `$scope.data` somewhere else or you mistake it for the returned `data` in .success callback function...

Comment: Hello Mr, Thank you for your reply   $scope.project_id=data.projectId it will not work because I need particular projectId but data.projectId contains full records of Id right.    also how would I use ng-init  in anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Put an ng-click on your tag like so:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" ng-model= values.projectId ng-click="viewRecord(values.projectid)"></a>
```

In your Angular Controller:

```
$scope.selected = {
   records:[]
};

$scope.viewRecord = function(recordId){
$scope.selected.records.push(record)

}
```

Then on your modal:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in selected.records">
<div><input type="text" value="r.projectId"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table>
 <thead><tr><td>  Edit </td></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="record_values in records ">
   <td>
 <a data-toggle="modal"  ng-click='disp(record_values)' 
         ng-href="#update"</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('myctrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('Projects').success(function (data) {                
$scope.records = data;  
$scope.disp=function( record)
{
$scope.project_description=record.projectId;
};
});
</script>
```

Comment: It is Working if any doubt ask me i will reply u thank u.